# Young Earth Creationists vs. Old Earth Creationists

Tags: young-earth-creation, old-earth-creation

There are two opposing sides with different arguments, YOung Earth Creationists and Old Earth Creationists. Could you please provide a summary of what is the most common scientific evidence that is used on both sides?

Comment: what's the difference between a "young earth creationist" and a "regular christian?" You seem to set them at odds, yet I (and I'm guessing many here) consider myself a "regular Christian" yet am also a Young Earth Creationist.

Comment: You know what I mean. One group believes one thing and the other the opposite, the names do not matter.

Comment: Actually, I don't. If you're talking about Young vs. Old Earth Creationists, please say so instead of using ambiguous labels like "regular Christians"

Comment: There are entire websites on all sides of this issue that discuss the evidence and the interpretations of the evidence that support any possible claim, from YEC to OEC to completely Naturalistic no God required origins of everything.  It takes hundreds of pages to discuss thoroughly, and even with that, you could add in several hundred lines from simple comments on the evidences in this site, and chats that have spawned from this site alone.  While I like the question, I think this is simply overly broad for this site.

Comment: Maybe you could refine the question to ask for a summary of the most common arguments used on both sides.  Also, the question title does not match the question.

Comment: Neither YEC nor OEC is fully consistent with the modern scientific view (i.e. physical evidence), though theistic evolution can be (by construction).  Given that neither YEC or OEC is supported scientifically, distinguishing between the two on the basis of physical evidence is like asking: which is the largest fruit on the planet, a strawberry or a plum?  You might instead wish to ask what the _Biblical_ evidence is.  That is a less expansive topic, and if you suppose God created the earth you may be willing to ignore _some_ physical evidence if the position is well-supported theologically.

Comment: @RexKerr Problem is, biblical evidence is always open to interpretation. There are only 4000 words in the Hebrew Language.

Comment: See also [What is the Biblical evidence for Old Earth?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/what-is-the-biblical-evidence-for-old-earth) and [What is Young-Earth Creationism?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/what-is-young-earth-creationism)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm very hesitant to answer anything on this as no matter what position I take, it will incite endless debate and comments.  However, I believe there is a simple answer that all sides can hold as acceptable truth.

The fact is that we *all* have the *same* evidence. Whether Atheist, Christian, Buddhist, Wiccan, YEC, OEC, the ***evidence*** never changes.

The difference lies in how we ***interpret*** the evidence.

To list off a few:

*Note, the OEC view is lumped with the Naturalist view, simply because they are similar.  OEC incorporates the idea of old-earth, and even the possibility of evolution after creation.  I'm not attempting to make any statement beyond that.*

- Evidence:  The existence of fossils of animals that are no longer alive. (Dinosaurs)

  - YEC view - Dinosaurs were real animals created by God.  They're mentioned in the Bible, and depicted in art all over the world (as dragons).  They were likely more prevalent before the flood, when conditions on the earth were drastically different (admittedly a supposition based on loose interpretation of scripture)
  - OEC and naturalistic View - What we're taught in the textbooks.  They lived millions of years ago, dies out long ago.
- Evidence - Similar structures in a wide variety of animals.  For example, whales have bone structure in their flippers remarkably similar to hands on humand and primates.

  - YEC view - We believe similar design is evidence for a common Designer.
  - OEC/Naturlaist view - Common features indicate a common origin, from which these current features evolved.

The list goes on forever.  The expanding universe, evidence for the Big Bang, geologic structures, dating methods, all have the same physical evidence.  The tests we can perform have the same results regardless of who is performing them.  Again, the difference is in the *interpretation*, not *evidence*.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the detailed answer, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: +1, well stated!  Though there is a sizable fraction (probably even a majority) of people who accept OEC that agree with YEC on some interpretations and disagree with scientific consensus (e.g. a common position among old earth creationists who I have known is that the order of events in Genesis is literally true).  For the purposes of your two examples, I agree: OEC and Naturalist views are in accord.

Comment: I am a pretty hard core OEC, I debated this one time with a NEC and in the end was told that perhaps God planted all those fossils in the bottom layer of the Grand Canyon to create a "history".  Kind of throws the whole evidence argument out the window lol.

Comment: Minor note: "common features" in the naturalistic theme can also show convergence rather than common origin

Comment: Well put.  I think this was a very fair and balanced presentation.

Comment: This is a great answer to a poor question. What do you think we could do in the way of re-writing the question so that this kind of answer would be required and we could re-opened it?

Comment: @Caleb - I don't know, honestly.  My original vote to close was based on the idea that the question was overly broad, but several hours later, I thought of a short, concise answer.  I bet others could, too.  I think, personally, that I voted to close inappropriately.  The question may not have been specific, but it is something that people ask, and if this really is a good answer, perhaps it's worth reopening.  You know as well as I do that similar questions will be asked again and again, so we should probably keep *some* of them open.

Comment: @DavidStratton: I think I agree. The question is what could we do to make this both as generally applicable as possible to cover this specific commonly asked question yet make it specific enough that it _requires_ a general answer like this one that does not turn into a permanent debate platform. Basically I'd be ok with opening it up for content like this, but we need a way to mitigate the floodgates of rubbish that this will tend to stir up as well. Thoughts?